# analyzer logic erros or death code

Tags: objective-c

Just before publish, I was checking my app with the analyzer. It found many logic errors, but all of them on the **cocos2d** classes such as `CCMenu`, `CCMenuItem` or `CCSprite`, which has been written by smart and good people that know quite a bit.

I can't go into their classes' code, and assuming that it has submitted before.

Does it have to do something with the way i use them? Or if I see a logic error in one of their `CCMenu` lines, that means its their error?

Does apple accept that logic errors? Is there a specific rule for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors may be real errors in cocos2d, but sometimes the analyzer reports false positives because it doesn't know all the invariants of the construct in question.

Dead code and dead store aren't usually a problem (that is not to say they shouldn't be removed).

In any case Apple doesn't even see these errors, because they don't show up in the compiled product. So I guess the answer is yes, Apple accepts these :)

Comment: thanks a lot. there is also 1 leak at the start always , that is also from the AudioToolBox, which i dont even use. hope this will not be a problem. another thing is that my app(which has so much graphics) is takes about 82mbyte total. is it ok? whats the max allowed ?

Comment: There is no limit to the the app's size that I know of. But if it is larger than 20mb you will only be allowed to load it while you are on WiFi.

Comment: i meant the INTERNAL MEMORY SIZE to operate that the analyzer shows when the app is running, not the memory of the app on hardrive...

Comment: ok, that might be  problem on older devices. There is no defined amount, but the more memory you need the more probable it is you're app will get killed first.